# "PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" while generating database backup

Tags: php, memory-leaks, large-files

I get the subj. when I try to make backup of my database in a text file.

```
function backup_tables($backup_filename, $tables = '*')
{
    $conf = new JConfig();
    $dbhost = $conf->host;
    $dbuser = $conf->user;
    $dbpassword = $conf->password;
    $dbname = $conf->db;
    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $return = "drop database if exists `$dbname`;\n\ncreate database `$dbname`;\n\nuse `$dbname`;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\n\n";

    $handle = fopen($backup_filename, 'w+');
    fwrite($handle, $return); $return = "";

    // get all of the tables
    if ($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    } else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
    }

    // cycle through
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM ' . $table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);
        $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $table . '`;';
        $return .= "\n\n" . mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE `' . $table . '`;'))[1] . " DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;\n\n";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $return .= 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' VALUES(';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                $row[$i] = str_replace("\n", "\\n", addslashes($row[$i]));
                $return .= '"' . (isset($row[$i])? $row[$i] : '') . '"';
                if ($num_fields - $i - 1) {
                    $return .= ',';
                }
            }
            $return .= ");\n";

            fwrite($handle, $return); $return = "";
        }
        if($return) {
            fwrite($handle, $return);
            $return .= "\n\n\n";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

This function works well by the exception that there is an memory leaks somewhere. It creates a file ~30 MiB and hungs with mentioned error. Memory usage of the httpd process increases uniformly while file generation is in progress. And one more: generation hungs at a large table (containing a log), but I think this is no matter 'cause information written row by row.

Comment: I would suggest using a Database tool to extract your SQL database and then export it as CSV or some other format. It's going to consume a lot more memory and time if you do it this way.

Comment: If you insist on this script, I would suggest upping the memory limit set in your `php.ini` file and that might fix it. But it will be A LOT slower than using a dedicated database ETL (Extract Transform Load) tools that are built into TOAD, Sequel Pro and other DB tools that are not written in PHP and made specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Using of external tools is highly undesirable in this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And one more: generation hungs at a large table (containing a log),
>   but I think this is no matter 'cause information written row by row.

Actually this is the cause: I should use `mysql_unbuffered_query` instead `mysql_query`. Now this function looks like this:

```
function backup_tables($backup_filename, $tables = '*')
{
    $conf = new JConfig();
    $dbhost = $conf->host;
    $dbuser = $conf->user;
    $dbpassword = $conf->password;
    $dbname = $conf->db;
    $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $return = "drop database if exists `$dbname`;\n\ncreate database `$dbname`;\n\nuse `$dbname`;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\n\n";
    $return .= "/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\n\n";

    $handle = fopen($backup_filename, 'w+');
    fwrite($handle, $return); $return = "";

    // get all of the tables
    if ($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    } else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',', $tables);
    }

    // cycle through
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $return .= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$table`;";
        $return .= "\n\n" . mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE `$table`;"))[1] . " DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;\n\n";

        $result = mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT * FROM `$table`");
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $return .= "INSERT INTO `$table` VALUES(";
            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
                $row[$i] = str_replace("\n", "\\n", addslashes($row[$i]));
                $return .= '"' . (isset($row[$i])? $row[$i] : '') . '"';
                if ($num_fields - $i - 1) {
                    $return .= ',';
                }
            }
            $return .= ");\n";

            fwrite($handle, $return); $return = "";
        }
        if($return)
            fwrite($handle, $return);

        $return = "\n\n\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the follow up on what you implemented as a solution. Always good to learn a few new things.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP answer here is to increase your max memory size if not your max execution time at the same time.

Outside of this being an exercise in re-creating the mysqldump command, is there a reason to perform this from within PHP code?

You might be better off using mysqldump or something like Holland http://hollandbackup.org/ to go through and dump each table individually.

Comment: Why do all of you suggest to increase max memory? I think there is need to understand the reason why this low-memory error appeared (and so I did).

Comment: To be brief, your PHP script is creating a LOT of objects due to the database queries which takes up a LOT of memory. Even though your machine may have 2048MB or how ever much installed, PHP has a default memory limit that is set in the php.ini file, some as little as 128MB.

Also, typically PHP scripts have an default execution time of 30 seconds. 

If you use up a a lot of memory, more than say 128MB and 30 seconds of execution, your script will fail to finish

Using a dedicated database tool does not rely on PHP or Apache and talks to the database directly which will be significantly faster

Answer (score 0):

Current answer uses a [deprecated function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-unbuffered-query.php). The new way to do this is using [mysqli::use_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.use-result.php).

In my case I ran into the exhausted memory error trying to write a large sql table into a file. Here's how I used it.

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

$sql = 'SELECT row1, row2 from table';

$fp = fopen('output.json', 'w');
if ($conn->multi_query($sql)) {
    do {
        if ($result = $conn->use_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
              $row1 = $row[0];
              $row2 = $row[1];
              $item = array('row1'=>$row1, 'row2'=>$row2);  
              fwrite($fp, json_encode($item));
            }
            $result->close();
        }
    } while ($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());
}

fclose($fp);
$conn->close();
```